# Validate that a Dictionary is a valid plist (before saving to user defaults)

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, plist

I want to save data to UserDefault from an unknown source.  The docs say that the dictionary must be a [valid Property List object](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuserdefaults/1414067-setobject?language=objc).

If the dictionary is not a valid plist, the app crashes.

```
class A {}
let invalidDict = [ "Key" : A() ]
UserDefaults.standard.set(invalidDict, forKey: "Key") 
// error: Execution was interrupted, reason: signal SIGABRT
```

I want it to just log the issue instead of crashing.  Surrounding with a do catch block does not work.

Is there a way to either prevent the crash or to validate an arbitrary dictionary is a valid plist format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class A {}
let invalidDict = [ "Key" : A() ]
PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(invalidDict, isValidFor: .binary) // false
```

But

```
let validDict = [ "Key" : "howdy" ]
PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(validDict, isValidFor: .binary) // true
```